# Windows7 and Virtual PC guest copy/paste intermittent delay

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-virtual-pc, copy-paste

I've been using Virtual PC for some time now and have not had any issues with copy and paste until I upgraded my host to Windows7 64-bit. After the upgrade sometimes when I copy and paste some text there is like a 15-20 second delay before it completes, this is very frustrating when I'm trying to get my work done.

The problem seems to be intermittent in nature, it seems to occur when I have not done a copy paste for a while. After the delay occurs copy and paste seem to work at normal speed until I don't copy and paste for a good length of time.

My question is, is there any solutions or patches that can fix this copy/paste issue for virtual PC running in a 64-bit windows7 host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - I switched over to [Windows7 "Windows virtual PC"](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/), and even though it says it doesn't support server guests they actually work great for me. Copy and paste works perfect now. I've tested with w2k3 and w2k8 (32-bit). The only glaring issue I've seen so far is a bit of overall diminished performance, which is probably just because i'm using a much higher resolution now.

Answer (score 0):

Neither VPC2004 nor 2007 is supported by Windows 7.  From what I've heard from other people, you are lucky that it is running at all.  I've had several tell me they couldn't even get it to run.

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion? I downloaded VPC 2007 64-bit from Microsoft, and I don't recall it saying anything about not being able to run in W7.

Comment: There is a new version of VPC that is Win7 compatible. It was released as a KB patch to Windows 7. You can see an article about it and links to the Win 7 compatible versions of VPC at http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/04/30/virtual-pc-for-windows-7-for-virtual-machine-or-xp-mode-free-download-kb958559/